# Application to download video from youtube

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, youtube

I making an application to view videos form youtube, and I think it is very easy to write a code to make the user be able download the videos and save it in the documents folder of the application, my questions are:

1) is it legal to do this, and is there any concern of the application being rejected?

2) is it possible to make the user watch the video and when he finish (watched all the video) get this data and save it, (not to download it again since he already watched the video and downloaded it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is a grey area. In general, you are not allowed to download copyrighted videos without paying for them. The official YouTube stance is rather interesting. This link tells you http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56100 that it is **not supported** except in *one* instance, that is, if you are downloading your own videos.

It then goes on to list various restrictions and policies on downloading your own videos. Note however, that **not supported** does not mean **debarred**. For further reading, please visit this link: http://news.cnet.com/8301-13739_3-9936833-46.html which is more readable for the general audience than a litany of policies. Therefore, in response to your questions:

1. This is in a grey area. Your application may or may not be rejected. Organizations are cracking down on copyrighted videos up on websites like YouTube. However, YouTube does not explicitly *debar* your application. A cursory Google search will reveal that there are many applications which allow you to download YouTube videos. For ethical concerns, I will not post any here.
2. What do you mean when you say "this data"? If all you are interested in are usage and view statistics of users on YouTube then I urge you to look at the YouTube API where you can do all this fun stuff without resorting to downloading a whole bunch of videos in your application.

Comment: actually I dont want the user to download any youtube video on the youtube website, there are specific channels on youtube that I show to their videos to the user and want the user to be able watch them when he is offline, and my second question is about since the user already watched the video, is there a possible way to cache the video directly after watching it.
Thanks

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the clarification. As far as your caching question goes, maybe you want to take a look here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/why-youtube-videos-arent-cached for some additional reading.

Answer (score 1):

1) Depends on luck. but, may be rejectd. Is far more likely to be rejected.

becauseof following Youtbe TOS. My app had been rejected by Apple.

For the following reasons:

---

22.4

We found that your app contains information that may allow its users to download YouTube content, which is not in compliance with the YouTube Terms of Service.

"...You shall not download any Content unless you see a "download" or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content. You shall not copy, reproduce, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display, sell, license, or otherwise exploit any Content for any other purposes without the prior written consent of YouTube or the respective licensors of the Content. YouTube and its licensors reserve all rights not expressly granted in and to the Service and the Content."

also refer following site question. that's very important. you will definitely need to read.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/88260-youtube-downloader.html

---

2) Available. But, like I said above, to download YouTube video have a potential risk.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) is it legal to do this, and is there any concern of the application
>   being rejected?

I'm not sure it's illegal; but it's definitely **against YouTube's TOS**. And, if you plan on getting your app approved in the App Store, then trust me : forget it.

> 2) is it possible to make the user watch the video and when he finish
>   (watched all the video) get this data and save it, (not to download it
>   again since he already watched the video and downloaded it).

Yep, that's doable.